# Why sometimes WPF DataTrigger not work?

Tags: c#, wpf

The control is a button and if I set the properties : Content and Background in design ,then the DataTrigger won't work at all(DataTrigger is to set the content and background properties)
And if I remove the properties value I set in the design,when I run the program and change the state property that will fire the trigger,the datatrigger works fine.
How could that be?
Here is my Xaml:

```
   <Style x:Key="DealBTN" TargetType="Button">
           <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  ..........
                  </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state, Converter={StaticResource Enum2string}}" Value="accepted">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BDC3C7"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Dealed"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state, Converter={StaticResource Enum2string}}" Value="rejected">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C0392B"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Canceled"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<Button  Style="{StaticResource DealBTN}" DataContext="{Binding}"   Content="Deal" Background="#FF1ABC9C" />
```

(the state property has INotifyPropertyChanged interface)

Comment: See [DependencyProperty Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). Style Triggers can't override local values. Use Style Setters to define default values.

Comment: Thanks,you are right. Such a complex priority rule